# Circumventing switch statement with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following C++ code which can be used to calculate arithmetic expressions.

```
struct Node
{
  char _operator;
  int _value;
  Node* _previous;
  Node* _next;
  double calculate()
  {
    switch(_operator)
    {
      case '#': return _value;
      case '*': return _previous->calculate() * _next->calculate();
      case '+': return _previous->calculate() + _next->calculate();
      case '-': return _previous->calculate() - _next->calculate();
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

I am very new to C++, and I understand that for OOP in general, it is better to use inheritance than conditional constructs, especially when they are deeply nested.

I want to know how would it be possible to convert the switch using inheritance though it would not be feasible for this example (Would it?)

Do I declare the `calculate` function `abstract` and write a subclass for each of the four `case`s of `switch`?

Comment: You can use inheritance and make `calculate()` method abstract. But why you do not use `Reverse Polish notation` for calculate arithmetical expression? Anyway, I do not think that you need inheritance here.

Comment: @gomons I understand that postfix evaluation would be easier, but that would defeat the purpose of what I want to learn. I want to know how this switch can be formulated into an inheritance structure.

Comment: "abstract" is a term for a class. The function would be "pure virtual", i.e. like this `virtual double calculate() = 0;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
class Expression {
    virtual double calculate() = 0;
}
class Literal : Expression {
    double _value;
    double calculate() {
        return _value;
    }
}
class Operation {
    protected:
        Expression* _previous;
        Expression* _next;
}
class Addition : Operation {
    double calculate() {
        return _previous->calculate() + _next->calculate();
    }
}
class Subtraction : Operation {
    double calculate() {
        return _previous->calculate() - _next->calculate();
    }
}
...and so on...
```

Answer (score 4):

Matter of taste. Do you think a "plus node" is a different kind of object than a "minus node"? One thing to think about is that you cannot modify the class of an object, so by making them separate classes, you lose the ability to change a "plus node" to a different kind of node.

In this case, adding four classes to get rid of a single switch statement seems to be overcomplicating things.

Comment: I fully acknowledge that it overcomplicates stuff here ofcourse, but everything aside, I want to know how to do it. How would I go about formulating those four subclasses?